# A generalization of the concept of finiteness

Tags: set-theory, terminology, cardinals

For concreteness' sake, let the underlying set theory be ZFC.

A set $x$ will be called *connex* (I've adapted the terminology [from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Connex_relation&oldid=906794035)) iff for every $y, z \in x$ either $y \subseteq z$ or $z \subseteq y$.

The following theorem characterizes finite sets:

> A set $x$ is finite iff for every non-empty connex set $y$ whose union is $x$, $x \in y$.

To see this, let $x$ be a set.

Suppose that $x$ is finite, and let $y$ be a non-empty connex set such that $x = \cup y$. If $x$ is empty, it must be that $y = \{\emptyset\}$, and indeed $x \in y$. If $x$ is non-empty, for every $a \in x$ choose a set $f(a) \in y$ such that $a \in f(a)$. It suffices to show that $x \in f[x]$. Choose any $a_1 \in x$. If $f(a_1) = x$, we're done. Otherwise, choose any $a_2 \in x\setminus f(a_1)$. By connexity, it must be that $f(a_1) \subseteq f(a_2)$, and therefore that $\{a_1,a_2\} \subseteq f(a_2)$. If $f(a_2) = x$, we're done. Otherwise, proceed in this fashion. After at most $|x|$ steps, we will obtain $x$.

Conversely, suppose that $x$ is infinite. Let $s$ be an infinitely countable subset of $x$, and let $s_1, s_2, \dots$ be a bijection from $\{1,2,\dots\}$ on $s$. Define $y_0 := x\setminus s$, and, for every $n \in \{1,2,\dots\}$, $y_n := y_{n-1}\cup\{s_n\}$. Observe that, for every $n \in \{0,1,2,\dots\}$, $y_n \subsetneq y_{n+1} \subseteq x$. Then $y = \{y_0, y_1, y_2, \dots\}$ is a non-empty connex set whose union is $x$, however $x \notin y$, since otherwise we would have $x = y_n$ for some $n \in \{0,1,2,\dots\}$, but then $x \subsetneq y_{n+1} \subseteq x$!

QED

Along similar lines, we can make the following definition for every cardinality $c$.

> A set $x$ will be called $c$-finite iff for every non-empty connex set $y$ of cardinality $c$ whose union is $x$, $x \in y$.

It can be shown that a set is $\aleph_0$-finite iff it is finite. One direction (namely $\Leftarrow$) is immediate from the characterization of finiteness given above. As for the other direction, let $x$ be an infinite set, and define $y = \{y_0, y_1, y_2, \dots\}$ as in the above proof. Then $y$ is a connex set of cardinality $\aleph_0$ whose union is $x$, however $x \notin y$, as was shown above.

---

**My questions**

Is the concept of $c$-finiteness known, perhaps under a different name or with some variation? Is there a simpler way of saying that a set $x$ is $c$-finite? In particular, is the following true?

> A set is $c$-finite iff its cardinality is strictly less than $c$.

Comment: When you say "A set $x$ is finite iff for every non-empty connex set $y$ whose union is $x$, $x\in y$.",  by "set $y$ whose union is $x$" -- what is the other thing we're unioning $y$ with?

Comment: @JackCrawford: We take the union of all the members of $x$. For instance, if $x = \big\{\{1\}, \{1,2\}\big\}$, then $\cup x = \{1,2\}$. Since in ZFC the members of every set are themselves sets, you can take the union of every set in this manner.

Comment: A set of cardinality $\aleph_0$ is not $2^{\aleph_0}$-finite.

Comment: @bof: How can this be seen?

Comment: For $t\in\mathbb R$ let $L_t=\{r\in\mathbb Q:r\lt t\}$. Then $\mathcal L=\{L_t:t\in\mathbb R\}$ is a connex set of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ whose union is $\mathbb Q$, and $\mathbb Q\notin\mathcal L$.

Comment: @bof: Nice! However, this shows, specifically, that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not $2^{\aleph_0}$-finite. Can we infer that any set of cardinality $\aleph_0$ is not $2^{\aleph_0}$-finite?

Comment: Yes, of course. A set in bijection with a $c$-finite set is $c$-finite.

Comment: @bof: OK. So this leaves my first question: is the concept of $c$-finiteness known, perhaps under a different name or with some variation? If so, what is it called? Also my second question remains: is there a simpler, maybe more mainstream, way of saying that a set is $c$-finite?

Comment: Suppose $f:A\to\mathbb Q$ is a bijection. Changec the definition of $L_t$ to: $L_t=\{a\in A:f(a)\lt t\}$. Okay?

Comment: I wouldn't know. Not an expert on set theory. By the way, don't much like the term "$c$-finite", doesn't seem to have much to do with finiteness.

Comment: @bof: Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure it needs a name. I think we can discuss the question "when can a set of cardinality $\lambda$ be represented as the union of a chain of $\kappa$ many proper subsets" (your question restated in plain language) without necessarily inventing any new jargon.

Comment: Note that the connex-based definition essentially says: $x$ is finite if and only if every $\subseteq$-chain of subsets of $x$ has a maximal element. This is what I like to call Tarski-finite (although the definition is often squandered on a variation of this definition which is equivalent to finiteness in ZF).

Comment: @bof. If $x,c$ are infinite cardinal ordinals with $x\ge c,$ let $y=\{(x\setminus c)\cup z:z\in c\}.$ Then $y$ is connex and $|y|=c$ and $\cup y=x$ but $x\not \in y.$

Answer (score 1):

The Dedekind cut argument showing that $\aleph_0$ is not $2^{\aleph_0}$-finite is universal, in a precise sense: the question of $\kappa$-finiteness amounts to counting Dedekind cuts (for somewhat vacuous reasons).

---

First, let's put a bound on the possible cardinalities of connexes, right off the bat. Trivially there are no connexes with union $x$ of cardinality $>2^{\vert x\vert}$, but it turns out we can do better. For a cardinal $\mu$, let $\overline{Ded}(\mu)$ (not standard notation, sadly) denote the smallest cardinal which is larger than the number of Dedekind cuts in any linear order of size $\mu$. For example, we have $\overline{Ded}(\aleph_0)=2^{\aleph_0}$ by considering the rationals. In general, it turns out that we can have $\overline{Ded}(\mu)<2^\mu$ (see e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.3099)).

Now suppose $Y$ is a connex whose union is $x$. We get an induced preorder $\triangleleft$ on $x$, given by setting $a\triangleleft b$ iff for each $y\in Y$ we have $b\in y\implies a\in y$. Elements of $Y$ correspond injectively (since connexes are *sets*, rather than *sequences*, of sets) to Dedekind cuts in this preorder (or in a linear order refining this preorder, if you prefer). So **there are no connexes with union $x$ of cardinality $\ge\overline{Ded}(\vert x\vert)$**, and hence $x$ is vacuously $\kappa$-finite for every $\kappa\ge\overline{Ded}(\vert x\vert)$.

- Note that this all relied crucially on the fact that connexes are defined as *sets*, rather than *sequences*, of sets.

---

In the other direction, suppose $x$ is infinite and there is a linear order $L$ of size $\vert x\vert$ with no maximal element, cofinality $\lambda$, and $\kappa$-many Dedekind cuts. Every "unbounded" set of Dedekind cuts in $L$ yields a connex whose union is $x$ but which doesn't contain $x$ as an element, and we can find such a set of any cardinality between $\lambda$ and $\kappa$ inclusive. Moreover, we can always ensure $\lambda=\omega$ (just consider $L+\omega$ ...), so this just says that every set $x$ is $\mu$-infinite whenever $\mu$ is infinite and $<\overline{Ded}(\vert x\vert)$.

---

Finally, every set is trivially (and annoyingly) $n$-finite for every finite $n$. Putting this all together, we have:

> If $x$ is infinite, then $x$ is $\mu$-infinite iff $\omega\le\mu<\overline{Ded}(\kappa)$.